# Capturing events in ajax modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, phaser-framework

Okay, so on this project I have kind of a complicated set up. This is a Phaser 3 game. I load all of my scripts in the header of the html file. `window.onload` calls `App.start()`, which configures and loads Phaser and the scenes. In my title scene class, I make an ajax call and retrieve an html template which is then displayed in a modal. I cannot seem to handle events within the generated modal to work.
I've tried:

```
$('#loginForm').on('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let values = $('#loginForm').serialize();
    console.log(values);
}
```

and

```
 $(document).on('submit', '#loginForm', (event) => {
     event.preventDefault();
     let values = $('#loginForm').serialize();
     console.log(values);
}
```

as well as trying to bind to the actual submit button. With everything I've tried, the page reloads, and processes the form as a get submission (values are appended to the URL). I should note that neither the `action` not `method` of the form have been set; only the `id`.

What can I do to capture the submit event?

EDIT: Adding code

App.js

```
let App = function() {};
App.prototype.start = () => {
    let scenes = [];
    scenes.push(Loading);
    scenes.push(Title);
    scenes.push(Start);

    let config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 900,
        height: 600,
        parent: 'gameDiv',
        scene: scenes
    };

    let game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    ...
};
```

Title.js (current testing)

```
class Title extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(){
        super({key: 'Title'});
    }

    preload(){}

    create(){
        let _t = this;

        let btnLogin = this.add.sprite(300, 350, 'login');
        let btnRegister = this.add.sprite(570, 350, 'register');
        let logoText = this.add.bitmapText(80, 100, 'Lombardic', 'Dragon Court', 108);

        btnLogin.setInteractive();
        btnRegister.setInteractive();

        btnLogin.on("pointerdown", (pointer) => {
            DC.templateCall('user', 'mode=login_tpl', () => {
                DC.templateFormHandler('loginForm', (event) => {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    let loginData = $("#loginForm").serialize();
                    console.log(loginData);
                    /*
                    modal.close();
                    Ajax.call('user', params, (result) => {
                        if(result.status){
                            _t.scene.start('Start', { fr: result.data.first_run, hc: result.data.has_char });
                        }else{
                            DC.modal('LoginError', '<div>'+result.error+'</div>', () => {});
                        }
                    });
                    */
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

templateFormHandler function:

```
templateFormHandler: (id, callback) => {
    $("#"+id).on("submit", callback);
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]? Your second code's event delegation looks like it should do what you're looking for, see https://jsfiddle.net/xvb2nhkf/

Answer (score 0):

I still can't find a legitimate reason for the code above not to work, but as a workaround, I've simply moved the handlers to the template file itself, and all works fine. A matter of scope somehow, I suppose.